# Get the content of another page's div with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like page.html to ajax-request the content of side.html and extract the content of two of its divs. But I cannot find the correct way to parse the response, despite everything I tried.

Here is side.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Useless</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a">ContentA</div>
<div id="b">ContentB</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Useless</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.0.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "side.html",
        success: function(result) {
            html = jQuery(result);

            alert(html.find("div#a").attr("id"));
            alert(html.find("div#a").html());
            alert(html.find("div#a"));

        },
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I access this page, I get no error, and the three alert()s yield undefined, undefined and [object Object]. What am I doing wrong? Example is live [here](http://xuneo.com/jqueryproblem/).

Comment: NB: I am not using load() because I need to extract several divs from the _same_ page, and I would like to load it only once.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
html = jQuery(result);
```

To this:

```
html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
```

And actually, even better you should declare this as a local variable:

```
var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
```

**Explanation**

When you do `jQuery(result)`, jQuery pulls the children of the `<body>` element and returns a wrapper around those elements, as opposed to returning a jQuery wrapper for the `<html>` element, which I tend to agree would be pretty dumb.

In your case, the `<body>` of sidebar.html contains several elements and some text nodes.  Therefore the jQuery object that is returned is a wrapper for those several elements and text nodes.

When you use `.find()`, it searches the *descendants* of the elements wrapped by the jQuery object that you call it on.  In your case, the `<div id="a">` is *not* one of these because it is actually *one of* the selected elements of the wrapper, and cannot be a descendant of itself.

By wrapping it in a `<div>` of your own, then you push those elements "down" a level.  When you call `.find()` in my fixed code above, it looks for descendants of that `<div>` and therefore finds your `<div id="a">`.

**Comment**

If your `<div id="a">` was not at the top level, i.e. an immediate child of the `<body>`, then your code would have worked.  To me this is inconsistent and therefore incorrect behaviour.  To solve this, jQuery should generate the container `<div>` for you, when it is working its `<body>` content extraction magic.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly, and your further explanations were of great help to me.

Comment: No problem, actually I felt bad / a bit embarrassed about giving you completely the wrong information in my first answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.get(url,function(content) {
    var content = $(content).find('div.contentWrapper').html();
    ...
}
```