# How to get content from another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, get

I have struggled with this problem for 2 days now. I've found MANY tutorials on similar topics but none have helped me solve my issue yet.

On a Volusion shopping cart I am trying to remotely grab content from the product page and save it's information in a variable for use on the shopping cart. I am unable to use php (not supported by Volusion) and am forced to do this by using javascript (as far as I know). The following code searches the cart items for a certain brand name "Palliser". If that name is present, it grabs the link, uses ajax to send a request to the page associated with the link, and grabs the info I need. It GETS the info I need, but in the process my page turns white and it leaves behind the year, 2013... I have NO idea why this is happening. This is my first time working with ajax so could someone PLEASE help!?!?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var seat_count = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var prodLinks = [];
    var numSeats = '';

    $('b.cart-item-name:contains("Palliser")').filter(function(index) {
        prodLinks[i] = 'http://xepwk.cjvgn.servertrust.com/'+$(this).parent('a').attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url:prodLinks[i],
            //data:string,
            async:false,
            success: function(result){
                var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
                var prodInfoArray = html.find('span.PageText_L660n').parent('b').parent('td').html().split('<br>');
                var numSeats = prodInfoArray[1];
                alert(numSeats);
            }
        });     

        i+=1;
});
```

Here is a link to the info that helped me get as far as I did: [Get the content of another page's div with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683736/get-the-content-of-another-pages-div-with-jquery-ajax?rq=1)

Comment: That's a very crude way of doing things, especially for an e-commerce site.

Comment: I'm sure it may be. Do you have any suggestions to point me in a better direction?

Comment: Joseph, I actually agree with you. The problem is Volusion does not grant us direct access to the database, so I can't do an sql search which I'm sure would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start ajax requests when DOM ready event fired. Because you don't need images and other staffs to begin ajax requests. Also `async:true` must be help in your situation.

```
var seat_count = 0;
var i = 0;
var prodLinks = [];
var numSeats = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('b.cart-item-name:contains("Palliser")').filter(function(index) {
        prodLinks[i] = 'http://xepwk.cjvgn.servertrust.com/'+
            $(this).parent('a').attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url:prodLinks[i++],
            //data:string,
            async:true,
            success: function(result){
                var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
                var prodInfoArray = html.find('span.PageText_L660n')
                    .parent('b').parent('td').html().split('<br>');
                var numSeats = prodInfoArray[1];
                alert(numSeats);
            }
        });     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, Having:

```
async:false
```

Loads your ajax-request synchronously and the request has to complete before you can do anything else. Try to change it to true or remove it (it is true by default).