# jQuery returns undefined while filtering AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm attempting to figure out AJAX in jQuery and am trying to extract the contents of one element on the page and inject it into another. Here's a test scenario I've been playing around with:

*1st page:*

```
...
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Load it!</button>
    <div class="content"></div>
...
```

*2nd page:*

```
...
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui nulla impedit a nostrum eos voluptas, quidem cum, consequatur suscipit voluptate officia sapiente laboriosam similique dignissimos praesentium obcaecati, nemo commodi, laborum!</p>
    </div>  
</div>
...
```

*script file from 1st page:*

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/index.html"
        }).done(function(response){
            $('.content').html($(response).find('.container').html());
        });
    });
});
```

Several posts on stack exchange like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938468/3124757) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683736/get-the-content-of-another-pages-div-with-jquery-ajax) have indicated that this is the direction I should be going in to grab 1 element's HTML from another page using AJAX. However, upon running the code on the first page, the contents from `.container` are not returned, and passing those jQuery methods to `console.log()` as so (`console.log($(response).find('.container').html());`) returns `undefined` to the console. What's wrong here?

Also, yes, I realize that using `.load()` is an option here, but I'd really like to learn how to use the AJAX method for jQuery as I believe it gives the programmer more find-tuned control.

Comment: The problem is that 'response' is not html yet. It is just plain text that has been received from the server. So jquery can not access that data as html yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change on how you get the response element container.

From:

```
$('.content').html($(response).find('.container').html());
```

To:

```
$('.content').html($($.parseHTML(response)).filter(".container").html());
```

Using `$.parseHTML()` will convert your response `string` to `DOM` nodes so that you can find those elements inside of it.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was wondering if jQuery might've not been smart enough to figure out the text was HTML— probably should've done 1 more google search.

Comment: @NoelForte Cool! Glad it helped.